# MSVC 19.11 / Visual C++ 2017: initializer list of size 1 and size_t type misinterpreted

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, language-lawyer, compiler-bug

Compiling the following code with MSVC 19.11 results in the output

`With 32: 0 99 2   With 64: 0 1 2` with a 32bit compiler, and in

`With 32: 0 1 2   With 64: 0 99 2` with a 64bit compiler.

The issue is that the single element initializer list is exactly of type `size_t`. Is this a compiler bug (I have not found it reported anywhere so far) and not a case of the standard being ambiguous (neither clang nor gcc have this problem)?

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using T = std::uint16_t;
    // fixed with uint32 / uint64 on 32 / 64 bit compilers, respectively,
    // but not with int32_t / int64_t
    {
        std::vector<T> s0;
        //  std::vector<T> s1{ 99u }; // OK
        //  std::vector<T> s1 = { 99u }; // OK
        std::vector<T> s1( { 99u } ); // BUG?
 // EDIT: std::vector<T> s1( {{ 99u }} ); // also OK
        std::vector<T> s2( { 40u, 70u } );
        std::cout << "With " << sizeof(0u)*8 << ':' << ' '
          << s0.size() << ' ' << s1.size() << ' ' << s2.size() << '\n';
    }

    {
        std::vector<T> s0;
        std::vector<T> s1( { 99ull } );
        std::vector<T> s2( { 40ull, 70ull } );
        std::cout << "With " << sizeof(0ull)*8 << ':' << ' '
          << s0.size() << ' ' << s1.size() << ' ' << s2.size() << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Command and Compiler(s):

```
cl.exe ilist.cpp & .\ilist.exe   # no extra cl arguments

cl.exe
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.11.25507.1 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved. (or x86)

x64\cl.exe and x86\cl.exe from
...\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\bin\HostX64\
```

Comment: Could also be a library bug - seems it selects the `vector::vector(size_t count)` constructor.

Comment: I wonder if this is related to [N3922](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html).  If you use `{{ value }}` it does work correctly.

Comment: I think we can simplify.  `int test( std::size_t ) { return 1; } int test( std::initializer_list<std::size_t> ) { return 2; }`; we have `test({7u})` preferring the `size_t` overload to the il overload.

Comment: No, that isn't the same; 19.00 passes the `test({7ull})` but still breaks on the above code.  Something funny is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a Visual Studio compiler bug.

A simpler example to show the problem:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <cstddef>

struct V {
    size_t sz;
    constexpr V(size_t s) { sz = s; } 
    constexpr V(std::initializer_list<int> l) { sz = l.size(); }
};

static_assert( V({size_t(3)}).sz == 1 );
```

Here `struct V` mimics `std::vector` with its two constructors in question.

According to [over.ics.rank#3.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.ics.rank#3.1)

> List-initialization sequence L1 is a better conversion sequence than list-initialization sequence L2 if
> (3.1.1)
> L1 converts to std​::​initializer_­list for some X and L2 does not...

So in this example `V({size_t(3)})` shall call the constructor `V(std::initializer_list<int> l)`, and it does so in GCC and Clang, but not in MSVC. Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3q64f7Yr7

This MSVC bug was fixed in Visual Studio 2022 version 17.9: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Wrong-constructor-of-std::vector-selecte/1652923